# Matplotlib - Find bar chart width value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hopefully a relatively straightforward question here- I have two barcharts I'm graphing. One of them has more categories, thus the width of each bar is smaller. See sample code/graph below (simple, standard plotting):

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

ax1.set_title("Sample Graph", size='16')
ax1.bar(df1.index, df1.c_destination, color='purple', alpha =1)
ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
ax1.set_xticks(df1.index)
ax1.set_xticklabels(df1['index'], rotation=45, ha='right', size='14')
ax1.patch.set_facecolor(color='gray')
ax1.patch.set_alpha(0.5)

ax2.set_title("Sample Graph Other", size='16')
ax2.bar(df2.index, df2.destination, color='purple', alpha =1)
ax2.set_axisbelow(True)
ax2.set_xticks(df2.index)
ax2.set_xticklabels(df2['index'], rotation=45, ha='right', size='14')
ax2.patch.set_facecolor(color='gray')
ax2.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
```

[image]

If the left graph has 12 bars and the right graph has 8 bars, how can I ensure the graph with fewer bars has the same bar width? I know I could define width in each, but I'm wondering if ax2 can access this value from ax1? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `bar(x, y, width=30)` can't you do this just using `width` argument? worth trying

Comment: I can but as I mentioned I would need to define both ax1 and ax2 individually. I'm trying to take advantage of the automatically generated width in ax1 and carry this over to ax2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [147]: [p.get_width() for p in ax1.patches]
Out[147]: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Mind that the bars actually do have the same width. They are all 0.8 data units wide. However, since the left axis range is larger, one data unit is smaller than in the right axis.

What you can do is use the same data range in both cases, e.g. by sharing the x axis,

```
plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex=True)
```

Comment: That's very interesting. I've tried this approach but it seems my ax1 has taken on the smaller range of ax2 (and labels disappeared). Since Max answered my question (I had no idea both were the same width), should I ask this question again separately? Specifically asking how to match bar appearance in both graphs?

Comment: It's your choice, you may also edit your question. But in any case make sure to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Btw. if it's only about missing values on the shared axes, plot the graph with the higher number of bars last.